# Test flask rest using curl. GET request with multiple query parameters

Tags: api, rest, flask, curl

I'm using Flask framework to create the rest API. the code below is the rest I've wrote.

```
@app.route("/posts/v2/list_by_date", methods=['GET'])
def public_posts_list_by_date():
    tracker_id = request.args.get('tracker_id')
    advanced_filters = request.args.get('filters')


    if advanced_filters:
        advanced_filters = json.loads(advanced_filters)
    else:
        advanced_filters = {}
```

the 'filters' is an array of parameters such as start_date, limit, offset, end_date.

And I want to test the rest and I used this command to test it:

```
curl http://172.31.32.22:3100/posts/v2/list_by_date?tracker_id=6939&filters=start_date=2020-11-30T15:05:05&end_date=2021-01-20T15:05:05
```

The problem is I don't receive the parameters of the filters in flask, it always empty.
I tried the above command and many other curl commands But still, it doesn't send the filters parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter `--data-urlencode` to encode the data beforehand.
See also [here](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html).

```
curl -G "http://172.31.32.22:3100/posts/v2/list_by_date" \
     --data-urlencode 'tracker_id=6939' \
     --data-urlencode 'filters={"start_date":"2020-11-30T15:05:05", "end_date":"2021-01-20T15:05:05"}'
```